# Geoserver Admin UI Behind Spring Cloud Gateway Not Working As Expected

Tags: spring-cloud, geoserver, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm working on moving our Geoserver 2.15.4 instance behind a Spring Cloud Gateway instance. These are all running in a standalone Docker instance on a local server. I've been able to get the requests for map data working fine. However the Admin interface is not functioning correctly. I can bring up the login page, but when I try to log in, it's not maintaining the route from the reverse proxy.

So instead of POSTing to `https://HOST/geoserver-admin/xxxx`, it's going to `https://HOST/xxxx`, which is failing.

My assumption is that I'll be able to pick up the X-Forwarded-* headers from the proxy, but what I can't figure out is how to update Tomcat and/or Geoserver configuration to pick up these headers.

Thanks!

Comment: So you're issue is with geoserver rather than gateway?

Comment: I believe so. I've configured a standard route for the gateway that is routing correctly for api requests, its just the admin ui that I'm having issues with. I just wasn't sure if there was something I wasn't understanding related to the gateway. Like I said my assumption is all I should need on the gateway side is to add the XForwarded filter to the route. Thanks

Comment: Did you set the proxy path in geoserver?